# Rails/HAML extraction of strings into locale files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, haml

I have a bunch of haml that I need to extract strings from into locale files for review by non-developers and translation.

Is there an automated way to do this?  A script that finds all the strings and organizes them into locale files?

Comment: basically https://github.com/douglasjsellers/herbgobbler for HAML

Comment: There's probably more options for you if you compile the haml into something else like HTML then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Started working on this just now:

https://github.com/shaiguitar/haml-i18n-extractor

It's WIP at the moment. Contributions are welcome.